# Formik's use with react-query onSubmit throwing "Invalid hook call"

Tags: formik, react-query

I have a React Native form that I'm trying to use Formik with react-query.

The problem is using `useQuery()` in a function called from `onSubmit` I am getting hook errors:

> Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() [Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

I believe I understand what the error is but I don't understand how to do a workaround to get this working.

The example I threw together just to demonstrate the issue:

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import axios from 'axios';

const getPokemonList = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon");
    return data;
};

function authenticate(username, password) {
    const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery('fetchLuke', getPokemonList);

    if (data) {
        {
            return (
                <Text>
                    {JSON.stringify(data,  null,  2)}
                </Text>
            );
        }
    }

    if (error) {
        return (
            <Text>{error}</Text>
        );
    }

    if ( isLoading ) {
        return (
            <Text>Retrieving Luke Skywalker Information...</Text>
        );
    }
}

export default function App() {

  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Formik
            initialValues={{ email: '' }}
            onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
                authenticate(values.email);

                actions.resetForm();
            }}
        >
          {({
              handleChange,
              handleBlur,
              handleSubmit, values }) => <View>
            <TextInput
                onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
                onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
                value={values.email}
            />
            <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Submit" />
          </View>}
        </Formik>
      </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly straightforward.

1. Create a variable and assign useQuery to it (in App, because useQuery is a hook and hooks can only be used in functional components)
2. Call the variable in your onSubmit or pass it to authenticate...

Answer (score -1):

react-query has a dependent query feature where the query only runs when a custom condition is satisfied.

Check the example below from https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/dependent-queries

```
// Get the user
 const { data: user } = useQuery(['user', email], getUserByEmail)
 
 const userId = user?.id
 
 // Then get the user's projects
 const { isIdle, data: projects } = useQuery(
   ['projects', userId],
   getProjectsByUser,
   {
     // The query will not execute until the userId exists
     enabled: !!userId,
   }
 )
 
 // isIdle will be `true` until `enabled` is true and the query begins to fetch.
 // It will then go to the `isLoading` stage and hopefully the `isSuccess` stage :)
```